# Javascript animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I trying to do simple animation on element on page

```
$(window).on('scroll',function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 500){
        $('#top-page').animate({ right: '50px' }, "slow");
    }else{
         $('#top-page').animate({ right: '-50px' }, "slow");
          }

});
```

the problem in that it never go to else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scroll` event fires many times during scrolling, so every time it fires a new animation is being added to animation queue. The queue grows to enormous size and you can't wait when the "right" animation would play.

To avoid this, you can use `.stop()` method which flushes the queue:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var sign = $(window).scrollTop() > 50 ? '' : '-';
  $('#top-page').stop().animate({right: sign + '50px'}, "slow");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh
}

#top-page {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-page">TOP PAGE</div>
```

Comment: It works as I expect but there are a small issue , I must scroll to top to apply the css

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll',function () {
    //var body = document.body; // For Safari
    var html = document.documentElement; // Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera

    if(html.scrollTop > 500){
        $('#top-page').animate({ right: '50px' }, "slow");
    }else{
         $('#top-page').animate({ right: '-50px' }, "slow");
    }
});
```